# Getting onclick to open popup from js variable

Tags: jquery, onclick, popup

i have a PHP/AJAX script and in the index.html there is an option to click on the text " click here to open " and it open a window from the variable

the code is :

< font color=blue>< a href="#" onclick="IntWebIM()">click here < /a>< /font>

i would like to hit " click here " and get the window opened like popup with some fixed height&width ..

could you please help ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to provide more details of your problem - but it sounds like you need to be looking at showModalDialog or a wrapper for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759(v=vs.85).aspx